# How to include VTK libraries into my project?

Tags: c++, vtk

I have already installed VTK and ITK on my machine (linux). Now, I am trying to read a nifti image, so I used a code to read it. I have to include some VTK libraries in the beginning like:

```
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkMetaImageReader.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkImageActor.h>
#include <vtkImageMapper3D.h>
#include <vtkImageReader.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
```

I need to use this superclass:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader> mMetaReader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkMetaImageReader>::New();
```

Still, they are unresolved. Although, I have run "cmake" in project directory, and I have specified VTK path.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(VTK_DIR "/home/workspace/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/")
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
add_executable(Project  Project.cxx)
target_link_libraries(Project ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you say "they are unresolved", what do you mean by *"they"*? If you get build errors, please copy-paste (in full, complete, as text and without modifications) the errors you get into the question.

Comment: I meant with "they": the inclusion. And the line code of superclass gives me an error "Type 'vtkMetaImageReader' could not be resolved".
I believe the error will be solved, if the inclusions are solved properly, but I don't know how to do that!

Comment: I replaced [tag:c] with [tag:c++] for you.

Comment: add the module manually in your target link libraries for starters.

Comment: @Mathieu Westphal, I tried that also, but it didn't work out.
Last thing I checked online, to build the project with cmake. It works fine, but it gives me an error: cannot find "vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/lib/libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2-8.1.so". Although I have it with same name!!!

Comment: We can't help you without an exact error message.

Comment: The error message is as written above: `cannot find "vtk/VTK-8.1.0/bin/lib/libvtkRenderingContextOpenGL2-8.1.so`. Although, it exists in VTK folder!

Comment: I would expect that the `VTK_DIR` should be set to `/home/workspace/vtk/VTK-8.1.0/lib/cmake`  and not the `bin` directory.